# Does Spotify resample their songs?

Tags: windows, audio, resampling

I was wondering how Spotify handles multiple audio formats (different combinations of 16/24-bits and frequency (Hz) on Windows? Do they resample the songs?

Thanks:)

Comment: This quitesion is off topic here.

Comment: Why is it off topic? I currently developing a program that does some audio transformation and I just wondered how Spotify handled this particular situation.

Comment: Because StackOverflow is for specific errors, not generic programming questions. This may be on-topic on Programmers, but probably not since it isn't actually programming related.